# Corny keg post sizes

Tags: kegging, corny-keg

My corny keg has two O-rings on each post is this ok?

As my other keg only has one, do I leave both O-rings on or remove one?

Comment: Is it working? If you take the second one off, does it stop working? There's no law about how many O rings to use. If you can make it work, that's good enough

Comment: Is it a new or used keg? If new, you should only need one. If it's used, the prior owner may have added a 2nd o-ring to help seal it up if parts were worn.

Comment: There are so many brands and types of cornys. Are they the same brand? If so it is strange that they are different. The standard is a Cornelius brand but there are others. See if you can't find the brand and then Google that type and see what the "standard" parts list looks like.